# Problem setting up iptables (LDAP traffic blocked)

Tags: centos, iptables, ldap

My application server is on a network protected by a organization wide firewall, and my server is also using `fail2ban`.  That said, I'd like to set up an additional layer of protection with `iptables`.  I'm having a little trouble with my configuration.

#### Requirements:

1. Deny access to everyone, then allow to a specific IP range (4.3.4.0/16)
2. Continued LDAP functionality in application (using`ldap_connect` in PHP)
3. Ability to retrieve external content via URL

#### Knowns:

- The application server IP is 1.2.3.4
- The LDAP server resolves to 1.2.100.200 and uses port 636
- My laptop's static IP is 4.3.2.1

#### What I've tried:

Starting with a vanilla `iptables` config that allows traffic over ports 22, 80 and 443, I added the following.

```
# explicitly allow ssh access from my laptop
iptables -A INPUT -s 4.3.2.1 -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# deny all traffic
iptables --policy INPUT DROP

# allow traffic from a specific IP range
iptables -A INPUT -s 4.3.4.0/24 -j ACCEPT

# allow traffic from LDAP server IP
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.100.200 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 636 -j ACCEPT
```

I save that config using `service iptables save`, then restart the service.

#### Problems:

If I'm already logged in, I can browse and use the application (except for one thing, below).  If I'm not logged in, LDAP authentication hangs.

The second issue is that I'm unable to access external content with the new config.  I retrieve data from another machine using HTTPS.  Is this just a matter of adding a rule to allow outbound traffic to the external machine's IP?

Comment: Could you focus in a problem at time? I think that the first question should be separated one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could the LDAP server be using non-standard ports?

You can see what port the ldap server is listening on via `netstat -tlpn`

> The second issue is that I'm unable to access external content with the new config

I'm assuming you mean that you're not able to connect to network resources from this machine after applying these rules. The requests are probably going out (since you apparently didn't set `OUTPUT`'s default policy to DROP) but the remote server's responses are being dropped by the firewall.

You can verify this is happening by monitoring the default policy's packet count as you generate the traffic you're concerned with:

```
root@xxxxxxvld02 ~ $ iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 157 packets, 18048 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 63 packets, 6998 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

In the above, the `157 packets` on the `INPUT` chain is the count of packets that ended up having the default policy applied to them (rules have their own counts to the left and don't change that number up top).

You probably want to create a rule that explicitly allows traffic related to already-existing connections:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Is there a way to log data using the `netstat -tlpn` command?  I ask because the LDAP query takes a microsecond, and if I am off by a little I won't see an LDAP entry in the list of results.

Comment: I added watch -n1 to the netstat command, tried to log in to the app.. and am not seeing any entry for the LDAP server IP (or anything related to LDAP).

Comment: `netstat -tlpn` shows you a list of the daemons listening on TCP ports locally. If you're trying to get a record of the client connecting, you can you use the `-j LOG` jump target to log the traffic to `/var/log/messages`. For example [this logs traffic coming from the laptop](https://dpaste.de/e2Xv)

Comment: Confirmed that the remote LDAP server operates over port 636.

Comment: Joel if you are still following could you help with the LDAP issue?  Confirmed traffic is happening over 636 which I made exception for in my rules.

Comment: So you've added the exception for tcp post 636 and the RELATED,ESTABLISHED rule in my above answer?

Comment: I didn't add the RELATED,ESTABLISHED rule till a moment ago.  LDAP authentication appears to be working properly now.   Getting external data still failing however.  Checking packets next.

Comment: OUTPUT packets are constantly increasing.  This may be due to a few ajax checks running in the background.

Comment: So it's working now?